# How to get a generic product description as a parameter in DialogFlow?

Tags: generics, parameters, dialogflow-es, product, entities

I'm trying to get a full description as a parameter in Dialogflow to store it in firebase along with other fields, the description includes numbers, characters, letter, etc.

These descriptions are for different types of products, that not always contain the same attributes, and it's very unpractical to make an entity for each type of product as there can always be new ones, so this is why I've decided to get the description in a parameter and store it in a single field for product description.

So I tried making a bunch of composite entities containing several system types, but somehow Dialogflow always fails on getting the whole description.  sometimes gets one part, then gets another part of it as a different one, for example if the description contains a color, or maybe a measure.

I have found several examples of composite entities, but haven't found something that makes exactly this I'm searching for, they're often used for categorizing very well structured entities, that always follow the same patterns example:

```
pizzas- entities:  size, topping, type, sauce.
cars- entities: model, brand, cylinders etc...
paint - entities: color, brand, solvent type.
```

But I'm trying to get a generic "product" entity that can contain any product and each of them need different attributes for example:

```
product: entities :?
-seventh generation liquid soap w/ lavender and mint scent 1 l gal.
-pizza with cheese and ham topping 8 slices.
-bar of body soap zote
-carboard box 12x13x5
-banana chips bag 150 grams
-cable tsj 12 meters #12343
```

etc..
I hope I explained well, I would be grateful to hear some ideas, maybe I'm not approaching to it the best way? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is challenging in DialogFlow unless your flow allows you to have an intent to detect any text as a product description.

Otherwise, I would approach this using generic entities and join them later to form the description.

Example (array params):

```
product_name: chips, cardboard, cable, soap, pizza, etc.. 
product_props: banana, mint, lavender, cheese, ham, etc..
size: composite (sys.numberxsys.numberxsys.number), m2, etc
length: meter, cm, 
quantity: bag, bar, gal
brand: zote, lays, etc..
```

then, you can join any detected value from above in one description.

so the `bar of body soap zote` would be `#quantity of body #product_name #brand` and you convert it to "bar zote soap"

You can also update the synonyms of these entities using DF API.

Hope that helps in any way.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you so much for your reply!! I did try something similar, but it would keep bringing other system entities that were not even in the custom ones I made, do you by any chance know if there is a way to restrict the entities that it should recognize?

Comment: can you show an example? if the entity is not listed in the parameters of intent (Action and parameters section), it would not be detected

Comment: Hi! Sure, well, in the training phrases it constantly add another entities which are not there for example: "2 pounds of white rice bob mill "    and I have quantity, product and brand for entities, and it makes rice as a last name, and bob as a name, as a new parameter, so constantly i have to manually adjust the parameters, this is hypothetical  since I'm working in spanish.